# How to get minute difference for every 2 datetime objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas DF

```
time                     #
2021-11-04 04:34:55 PM   1
2021-11-04 04:36:55 PM   2
2021-11-04 04:39:55 PM   3
2021-11-04 04:45:55 PM   4
2021-11-04 04:46:55 PM   5
2021-11-04 04:47:55 PM   6
2021-11-04 04:49:55 PM   7
2021-11-04 04:53:55 PM   8
2021-11-04 04:57:55 PM   9
...
```

I want to calculate the time difference between each number and store that in a column for each value. So the column will have output
`02:00, 03:00,....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps simply:

```py
df['time'].diff()
```

Or, if `time` is the index():

```py
pd.Series(df.index).diff()
```

Comment: thanks I know this question seems really simple and easy now but this was rather difficult to search for how to do, at least for me.